# "Украино-"

Tags: орфография

Здравствуйте.
В нашем богоспасаемом информагентсте с давних времен принято писать "украино-российский", "украино-американский" и так далее. Мне кажется, что это неправильно. "Украино-" допустимо в словах типа "украиноязычный", а если с дефисом - то все-таки "украинско-". Рассудите, пожалуйста.

Comment: А хороший вопрос! +1. Задумался. А в самом деле. **"Украиноязычный"** -- говорящий на **украинСКом** языке. "Украино-американские отношения" -- отношения между Украиной и Америкой. (или *украинско-*, разберёмся )

Почему тогда не написать **"украинскоязычный"** ? Но так не пишут. *Англоязычный*, *франкоязычный*, но не *английскоязычный* или *французскоязычный*.

Почему так?

Comment: Или ещё проще пример пришёл в голову. Ещё со школьных времён многим детям непонятно -- почему **англо**-русский словарь, а не английско-русский? Но, в то же время, вполне правильно говорить: немецко [неметСКо]-русский словарь.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, в таких словах, как англо-русский, франко-русский и т.п., суффикс *-ск-* относится к обоим корням. Ещё можно пояснить тем, что после суффиксов попросту не может находится корень.  Та же ситуация и с "украиноязычный". 
В слове "немецко-русский", уважаемый [[@Nikolja](/users/1112/nikolja)](/users/1112/nikolja), нет суффикса *-ск-*, иначе что значит слово "немец"?  Корень это всё.

Добавочка: видимо, есть и исключения. Мне тут вспомнился "русско-белорусский" и "белорусско-русский", но это, скорее всего, из-за того, что неудобно в словах с корнем "рус" писать так, как с другими. Крепко всё-таки суффикс *-ск-* закрепился за этим словом.

Answer (score 0):

Русский - прилагательное субстантивированное, поэтому в нем в подобных случаях суффикс не выделяют. А вот "белорусско-" потому, что иначе будет относиться к белорусу, а не Белоруссии.
С остальным надо разбираться детально, но судя по всему подобное написание правильно, поскольку относится к Украине, а не украинскому. Сраните: украинско-русский словарь. Не "украино-". 
Еще сравните: юго-западный, не "южно-"